# using react router with next.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, routes, react-router, next.js

I am learning how to use Next.js/React for my application. I am currently researching the topic of routing and I had a few questions. I know that you can use react-router for React (I used vue-router before). However, I do not know if I need to use react-router with Next.js and how I would use it if I could. I am currently using a pages directory to hold pages to redirect to. How can I redirect to different pages in React/Next?

Here is some sample code to implement it in:

```
Class Login extends Component {

  state = {
    user: {},
  }

  loginUser = (e) => {
      loginUser(this.state.user)
        .then(response => {
          console.log(response);
          if (response['username']) {
            console.log('yippee!');
          }
      });
  }

}
```

After yippee, I want to redirect to /home which is in the pages folder.

Comment: I suggest you have a read through [`next/router` documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/router). In particular the `withRouter` section.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For your first question I need to say: No, you don't need `react-router` in `Nextjs` it will use something called file-system based router which you can read more about it [here](https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/introduction)

So after you set up your routes if you want to **Navigate** to them you have two options:

**first** using the `Link` Component from `next/link`: more about it [here](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/link)

**second** using the `router` from `next/router` which you can Navigate around like `useHistory` from `react-router`: more about it [here](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/router)

example from the doc:

```
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'

function ActiveLink({ children, href }) {
  const router = useRouter()
  const style = {
    marginRight: 10,
    color: router.asPath === href ? 'red' : 'black',
  }

  const handleClick = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    router.push(href)
  }

  return (
    <a href={href} onClick={handleClick} style={style}>
      {children}
    </a>
  )
}

export default ActiveLink
```

So in your case, using this is how you can redirect:

```
import { withRouter } from 'next/router'

Class Login extends Component {

  state = {
    user: {},
  }

  loginUser = (e) => {
      loginUser(this.state.user)
        .then(response => {
          console.log(response);
          if (response['username']) {
            console.log('yippee!');
            //here is what you need:
            this.props.router.push('/your-route');
          }
      });
  }

}

export default withRouter(Login)
```